# Angular v9 @Output emitter not received by parent component

Tags: angular

I am trying to emit an event from a child component when a button is clicked and then act on it from the parent component. The code compiles fine, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

As far as I can tell, I am implementing [this example](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#component-interaction) correctly.

You can preview the app on [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/plunk/hZUXlNz7SdiocbQy). When clicking on the grey square, check the debug console. The logs from the method that emits the event work, but the ones in the receiving event don't.

Folder structure:

```
app
  \- map
  \- search
```

And the files inside of the folders:

```
app
  \- map
      -- map.component.css
      -- map.component.html
      -- map.component.ts
  \- search
      -- search.component.css
      -- search.component.html
      -- search.component.ts
  -- app-routing.module.ts
  -- app.component.css
  -- app.component.html
  -- app.component.ts
  -- app.module.ts
```

So to follow the event, it starts with a button in the search.component.html file...

```html
...
<span uk-icon="icon: location" (click)="centerOnGeolocation()" class="uk-icon"></span>
...
```

which fires the event in the app-search component (successfully), from search.component.ts...

```js
export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() startGeolocate: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter();

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  centerOnGeolocation() {
    console.log("geolocation button");
    this.startGeolocate.emit("message");
    console.log("after emit");
  }

}
```

The map component which has the search component tag in it, map.component.html...

```html
...
<app-search (startGeolocate)="onStartGeolocate($event)"></app-search>
...
```

which points to the map component's onStartGeolocate event, map.component.ts...

```js
onStartGeolocate(msg:string) {
    console.log(msg);
};
```

However, the message is never received.

From the console...

```
search.component.ts:17    geolocation button
search.component.ts:19    after emit
```

I am not sure where I'm going wrong as this seems to be everything the documentation tells me to do.

Comment: It works fine here : https://ng-run.com/edit/l9B6DtM2PB0DCwRINOsT
Are you sure you imported `EventEmitter` from '@angular/core' ?

Comment: hmm, i see it's working there, the EventEmitter is imported at the top of search.component.ts (equivalent to the test test.component.ts in your example. but one difference is that your example has the receiving event in the app.component.ts not another component